# Login-AzureRmAccount from VS Code terminal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-powershell

When I try to login to Azure RM from VS Code terminal it just hangs. No prompt with login / password is shown.

Is there any way to get logged in from that terminal? Otherwise running / debugging Azure PS scripts becomes more complicated than it should be :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The login window pops-up in the background... if you minimize all your windows you'll eventually find it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for a moment, then you could see the login page.

According to your description, I suggest you could select Non-interactive login. You could create a service principal that can access resource. Please refer to this link:[Use portal to create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal). You will get clientid and client secret. You could use the following code to login your Azure account.

```
$subscriptionId=""
$tenantid=""
$clientid=""
$password=""
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it definitely worth using service principal in scripting environment. But I'll accept the answer of @bmoore-msft, since it better fits my scenario :)