# Sign in to Azure Account from VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory, azure-marketplace

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code 1.19.2. It's a clean installation.

I've installed Azure Extension Pack from Microsoft with Azure Account (0.2.2). But I am not able to sign in to my Azure subscription. When I type Azure: Sign In in the commands pallete (CTRL+Shift+P), it only shows Azure: Logging in... in the bottom purple line, but nothing happens. I am not signed in.

As far as I know it should open browser window with login screen, but it does not. My default browser is Edge, my operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise x64 1709 with all updates.

How to sign in to my Azure subscription?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: This is not related to programming, is it?

Comment: Connection to Azure is not, but then it is. But I have been sent here from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da809b97-cba3-4068-bf75-99bf9b183ffc/not-able-to-sign-in-to-my-azure-subscription-from-vs-code

Comment: You may refer the below links and see if it helps,

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/27 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713788/login-azurermaccount-from-vs-code-terminal

Comment: I don't use proxy, therefore it is not related to me. And the manual connection is not a solution, because I can connect manually from a separate PowerShell window :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because your corporate network has blocked the proxy to execute the Azure: SignIn command. So the solution is to add value HTTPS_PROXY in the environment variable to allow the web browser to open up the Azure Sign in the login page.

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
```

Answer (score 31):

For me I just copied the Azure tenant ID from the portal: Go to `ActiveDirectoy` in Azure then go to properties you'll see the tenant ID.

Now just paste the tenant ID in vscode: `File->Preferences->Settings`, then search for keyword "tenant" and add your Azure tenant id.

Comment: This just saved me. Thanks

Comment: Saved after a frustrating search

Comment: Much thanks. I have several azure accounts and for some reason just one of them was unable to retrieve subscriptions. I wonder how much time, globally, is consumed trying to resolve wonky auth issues like this. Anyway, I appreciate you saving me some time.

Comment: how did you know to look for that?

Comment: wao this is a bug with azure cmd in vscode it dosnt update this var, thanks for the post!

Comment: An ultimate answer. You save me so much time, thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

Can you see this strip pop out?

[image]

**Edit**: if not install [Azure Tools For VScode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradygaster.azuretoolsforvscode)

only after clicking "Sign in" you should get a browser window open where you have to paste the code.

Comment: No, I don't see it. I hit CTRL+Shift+P and to the command line I write Azure: Sign In and click it. Then in the bottom of the screen I see Azure: Loggin In... and nothing else.

Comment: I have it installed. It's a part of Azure Extension Pack https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-azureextensionpack

Comment: try to install it separately and/or reinstall the extension pack

Comment: also , if you are trying to log in with a Microsoft account (such as a hotmail.com, live.com, or outlook.com) you will have to set the azure.tenantId setting in the preferences

Comment: It's a clean installation of VS Code on a clean installation of Windows 10. I also tried it before the system reinstallation, but it was still the same. I tried uninstalling the extensions, installing it again, uninstalling VS Code and removing all VS Code folders, but it's still the same. I think it's a bug, or I do something completely wrong. I don't even have the chance to write my account because I don't see any sign in page. Therefore free/AAD account is not the case.

Comment: If you are trying with "Azure: Sign In" command try  "Azure: Login" and vice versa

Comment: "Azure: Sign In" ends with "Azure: Loggin in..." in the bottom of VS Code screen (the purple line) and nothing else even if I keep for 30+ minutes.
"Azure: Login" ends with "command 'azure.login' not found"

Comment: If so please try to install the "Azure Tools" extension i linked to even though it is part of the extension pack and try again

Comment: Nice. I had to uninstall also the extension pack. But when I then installed only Azure Tools, I was able to log in. But when I then installed the extension pack, I got again only the "Azure: Logging in..." message and I was not able to log in. Therefore there is some bug/collision.

Comment: you can install only what you need from the pack to avoid the collisions.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 2):

For me I was confused by the message, it copies the code to your clipboard automatically, I'm just dumb..

Comment: The same happened to me lol!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and was rectified by changing my default browser from Edge to Chrome. Signing in via Chrome worked whereas Edge signed in successfully in browser but not reflected in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the VS Code to the latest version, Also ensure environment variable contains the necessary http proxy. No need to change the default browser