# VS Code Azure Account Extension asking to Select Subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

My VS Code Azure Account Extension is asking me to "Select my Subcription" . When i click on Select subscription it pops a message on the right bottom corner saying "No subscriptions were found , setup your account at [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free%22). Even though i click on the link and login, still it doesn't show my PAYG subscription. Same thing is with the Storage Account Extension. Any idea why Azure cannot find the subcription. I am logged in to Azure with my PAYG subscription and i can display all resources in the Powershell Integrated Console inside VS Studio. I tried logging out and logging to Azure, multiple times, restarted VS Code, still the same

Comment: Is it your free tier account?

Comment: It is a PAYG account that i subscribed to 2 days back

Comment: Can u try login to Azure using powershell? Just to make sure it is VS Code specific and not account settings related

Comment: Yes, i am logged in to Azure using Powershell Integrated Console in VS Code. I can see the PAYG subscription if i do Get-AzSubscription, i can see the storage account and resource groups also. No issues there at all. I tried using VS code in another laptop and i am facing the same issue, exactly described here in the thread, but PS Integrated console works fine, no issues at all

Comment: The solution provided here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276651/sign-in-to-azure-account-from-vs-code/62752140#comment119288191_62752140

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue as you described. What worked for me was to hit CMD + SHIFT + P (CTRL + SHIFT + P) and then search for '**Azure Sign In**'. A browser window should show up, asking you to sign in. Then suddenly your Microsoft Azure Account Extension should work again.

Comment: I did that it didn't work. When you open VS Code first time, you get Azure Sign in option even on the Azure Account Extension on the left hand side and Azure Storage Extension also. I signed in from there and now if i press CTRL+SHIFT+P it shows Azure:Sign Out. Somehow it's not finding my subscription which is a PAYG subscription. If i click on Select Subscriptions on the Extension it take me to the browser window and i am already logged in there, so everything stays the same

Comment: I also had this issue, and what did the trick for me was re-selecting my tenant.  CMD + SHIFT + P (CTRL + SHIFT + P) and search for `Azure: Select Tenant`. Most likely you will only have a single option to pick from here and then you will be re-prompted to sign in. Additionally, you can check out the [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/wiki/Troubleshooting#unable-to-list-subscriptions) for this issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I suspect having logged in before with a free subscription somehow messes things up. Was able to get past it by using command `Azure: Sign In to Azure Cloud`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VS Studio Code and my Subscription, following another post I initially created a Web App in a resource group via the Portal. Logged out and re-logged in and saw no difference. Saw neither the resources of web app created or subscription in Visual Studio Code

Then I went to View->Command Palette then did an Azure Sign in (even though it said I was signed in) then Azure Select Subscription, with this I suddenly saw my subscription, which I selected.

Then I saw the resource group I had created and also my subscription was available to use in VS Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with below steps.

1. Log out (if logged in) from your azure account (from the default browser).
2. Login again back to portal.azure.com using the security code.
3. Go back to VS Code and using command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) login to azure (Azure: Sign In ).
4. This will open to the browser where you are already logged in (Step 2).
5. The subscription should be available now on the VS code.

Seems like the subscription information is not available while logging from the password option (may be applicable only for free tier accounts).

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the directory `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Code`
then sign in to VS Code again on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only VS Code re-install fixed the issue. When uninstalling, I also removed the folder mentioned by @homopluvial:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming
```